# WKWebView increase font size without adding horizontal scroll

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

So, the problem is following:
We have simple text, :

```
Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp; NED test test&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp; NED test test&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp;Text&nbsp; NED test test&nbsp;
```

And we use WKWebView for displaying it:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(text, baseURL: nil)
```

We will see the result like

[image]

As you see the font is quite small, so I want to increase it.
If I try to do

```
    private func viewPortScript() -> WKUserScript {
        let viewPortScript = """
            var meta = document.createElement('meta');
            meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
            meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width');
            meta.setAttribute('initial-scale', '1.0');
            meta.setAttribute('maximum-scale', '1.0');
            meta.setAttribute('minimum-scale', '1.0');
            meta.setAttribute('user-scalable', 'no');
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
        """
        return WKUserScript(source: viewPortScript, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    }
```

or

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust='200%'
```

It will increase the font, but we will see horizontal scroll in this case

[image]

Is there way to increase font size but without horizontal scroll

Answer (score 0):

Find the issue...

```
webView.loadHTMLString(text.replacingOccurrences(of: "&nbsp;", with: " "), baseURL: nil)
```

We need to remove nbsp https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space